# QuickBooks SDK and ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, quickbooks-online

I'm curious if someone has documentation and insights regarding the compatibility of .NET Core 6 with the `IppDotNetSdkForQuickBooksApi`.

I consulted this https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/sdks-and-samples-collections/net/configuration but didn't find a thing that says that it is compatible with .NET Core.

Comment: This looks like a plain REST API - and that is **definitely** compatible with .NET Core - just make those HTTP calls and interpret the results as needed